Removing the statement "Powered by" under GPLv3
I would like to know, if I can remove the statement "Powered by GrandNode" from the footer, where GrandNode published under the license GPLv3.
Here is the official website: https://grandnode.com/

Could we ask that you either accept an answer to this question (by clicking the tick outline) or edit the question to indicate what remains, to your mind, unanswered?  That's the social compact of the site; please accept my apologies if you already know this.

GPLv3 s7b does provide for a requirement for "preservation of specified reasonable legal notices or author attributions in that material or in the Appropriate Legal Notices displayed by works containing it", which could perhaps be stretched to include a "Powered by GrandNode" footer.  But s7 goes on to note that "If you add terms to a covered work in accord with this section, you must place, in the relevant source files, a statement of the additional terms that apply to those files, or a notice indicating where to find the applicable terms.".
So I registered and downloaded the source, and I find that message defined in src/Web/Grand.Web.Common/Middleware/PoweredByMiddleware.cs.  Not only is there no such requirement in that file, but there's no licence declaration at the top of it (or any other source file I chanced to look at).
I think you're fine to remove it.  That said, I'm no coder, so my analysis may be flawed; also, IANAL/IANYL.  If you're planning on betting a company on this, you should take professional advice.
